# Git Add * vs Git Add '*.js' : What is the difference?

Tags: git

What is the difference between these two? I am using Selenium Web-driver in JS but sometimes the '.js' doesn't work or doesn't add everything I am working on.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with files in subdirectories. But you must be more clear about your situation and problems. Please show what files you have, what commands you run and what is the outcome of these commands including any error you get. This question is already spoiled with votes. My advice to you is to delete the question and create a new, better one with more details.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally, one will add all changed files to the staging area and the other will only add changed files matching `*.js` to the staging area.

However, I suspect that you are asking a different question, so you will need to elaborate as to what you are really asking.